# setup of Pyramid on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyramid

Following [these steps](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/tutorials/gae/index.html#appengine-tutorial) produces the following:

```
$ python2.5 ../appengine-monkey/appengine-homedir.py --gae $GAE_PATH pyramidapp
New python executable in pyramidapp/bin/python2.5
Also creating executable in pyramidapp/bin/python
ERROR: The executable pyramidapp/bin/python2.5 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5' (should be '/Users/lostdorje/Development/workspace/pyramidapp')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I see some others are having [similar problems](http://code.google.com/u/@WRZXRVxYAxNMWQk=/updates/projects).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't seen this exact problem, but when I was developing on a mac,  the things I did that worked was installing python2.5 from activestate or homebrew or macports and using buildout and using the appengine recipe at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rod.recipe.appengine/1.4.1. hope that helps

Comment: I also used Pyramid with AppEngine. I used Ubuntu and deadsnake's ppa https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes for python2.5. Everyhing was running fine. Later I had trouble with too long start-up times (AppEngine kills your request if the app is taking too long to respond), so I left AppEngine.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the ideas.  Never got this to work together, but we've since moved off of AppEngine as a backend.

Comment: That tutorial is a bit outdated. It should work with http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/tutorials/gae/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [Pyramid on Google App Engine example](https://github.com/jensens/pyramid-gae-tutorial). Its based on `zc.buildout` and on the tutorial mentioned in the question, but it is running with `Pyramid 1.4` and some helper recipes.